# getting REST (ws) with json,jackson format from a phonegap client

Tags: android, json, rest, cordova, jackson

I'm trying to connect between my REST web service which sends json jackson format as :

```
{
"returnCode" : 0, "userId" : "110551",
"offices" : [{"officeNum" : 1, "officeName" : "example1"}
,{"officeNum" : 2, "officeName" : "example2"},]
}
```

and my phonegap mobile application. I'm getting an error of connection.
i was using an example from [HERE](https://www.openshift.com/blogs/day-10-phonegap-mobile-development-for-the-dummies) and it doesn't seems to work (i left the format of example undamaged for reviewing).

```
    var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:7101/examplerestRest/jersey/example/1,abcd,12';
$.mobile.loading( 'show',{});
$.ajax({
    url : url,
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function(data){
        $.mobile.loading( 'hide',{});
        $.each(data , function(i , obj){
            var template = $("#blog-template").html();
            obj.publishedOn = $.timeago(obj.publishedOn);
            $("#blogs").append(Mustache.to_html(template,obj));
            $('#blogs').listview('refresh');
        });
    },
    error : function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus, errorThrown) {   
        $.mobile.loading( 'hide',{text:"Fetching blogs.."});  
        alert("error");  

    }
})
```

am i doing things wrong , maybe another approach could be better ? thanks

Comment: what is "error of connection"?

Comment: Well for one thing the entire return data set is not an array. I think you're trying to iterate over the 'offices' array which should be `data.offices`. Second you're accessing a field `publishedOn` which doesn't appear in your json.

Comment: this structure based on an example. i paste it here to keep the original example. my code is different